# Order of AfterMap in Automapper

Tags: c#, automapper

Is there any way to specify which AfterMap function should be executed first? 
For example I have this code:

```
 cfg.CreateMap<ClassA, ClassA_DTO>()
                 .AfterMap((source, dest) => ...
                 .AfterMap((source, dest) => ...
                 .AfterMap((source, dest) => ...


 //I need this aftermap to be executed first.
 cfg.CreateMap<ClassB, ClassB_DTO>().AfterMap((src, dest) =>
 {
     foreach (var ... in ...)
     {

     }
 });
```

But the problem is that ClassA contains ClassB.

Comment: By "Parent" do you mean "Containing class"  or "Parent class"?

Comment: My mistake. I mean that ClassA contains ClassB

Comment: If you need this kind of fine-grained control you might have to use a [custom type converter](https://automapper.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Custom%20Type%20Converters)

Comment: Custom type converter docs are now here http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Custom-type-converters.html

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't, and I probably won't add it. It's way too confusing. I'm not sure what you're trying to do in your mapping, but this much custom configuration might be a good case of manually mapping things, which is as explicit and obvious as you can get.